# "type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'" only in fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane, swift-package-manager

I'm using resources inside an SPM target. I've defined the resources like this:

```swift
.target(name: "Workflow",
        dependencies: ["Common"],
        path: "Workflow",
        resources: [.process("Resources")]),
```

This works well in Xcode but if I use fastlane to compile my project either locally on on Azure DevOps I get the following error message:

```swift
type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'

if let path = Bundle.module.path(forResource: named, ofType: extension) {
```

Inside the `Fastfile`, the Xcode version is defined as

```swift
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

  before_all do

    xcversion(version: "~> 12.1")
```

I have yet to figure out why compilation works in Xcode but not when using fastlane.

Comment: OK, I figured out that what fastlane was doing was creating an `xcodeproj` from the SPM (`spm(command: "generate-xcodeproj")`). This project then does not support `Bundle.module` and doesn't contain the resources, either. `spm(command: "build")` doesn't work for me, either, since it also compiles to macOS which doesn't support `UIKit`. I haven't found a good solution yet.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: I did not, sorry.

Comment: I happened upon a solution that works. I'll post it as an answer here in a second...

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Wrap the `Bundle.module` code in an `#if SWIFT_PACKAGE` block.

**Longer version**:
Since Xcode prefers *convention over configuration* it seems like it knows how to manage the compilation of `Bundle.module` when the project is a package. When you’re not directly compiling the package in Xcode, e.g. when Fastlane creates an xcodeproj to compile the package code, we need to instruct the compiler on what to do with language features that are exclusive to packages, e.g. `Bundle.module`.

In my case, I wanted to expose a url to a file in the package bundle so that consumers of the package could load that file. I had to wrap that code in `#if SWIFT_PACKAGE` to prevent the compiler error in Fastlane:

```
#if SWIFT_PACKAGE
public extension Emoji {
  static var keywordsURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "emoji-keywords", withExtension: "json")
}
#endif
```